# Typing and pint

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, typing, pint

I'm using `pint` to use and convert units. I wanted to create classes which restricts the quantities only to "[time]" or "[length]" dimensions, so as a first approach I did the following:

```py
from pint import Quantity, DimensionalityError

class Time(Quantity):
    def __new__(cls, v: str | Quantity) -> Quantity:
        obj = Quantity(v)
        if not obj.check("[time]"):
            raise DimensionalityError(v, "[time]")
        return obj

class Length(Quantity):
    def __new__(cls, v: str | Quantity) -> Quantity:
        obj = Quantity(v)
        if not obj.check("[length]"):
            raise DimensionalityError(v, "[length]")
        return obj
```

At runtime it works as expected, i.e: I can do the following:

```py
1hour = Time("1h")    # Works ok, variable 1hour contains `<Quantity(1, 'hour')>`
bad = Time("1meter")  # As expected, raises pint.errors.DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from '1meter' to '[time]'
1meter = Length("1meter") # Ok
bad_again = Length("1h")  # Ok, raises DimensionalityError
```

However, from a typing perspective, something is wrong:

```py
def myfunc(t: Time) -> str:
   return f"The duration is {t}"

print(myfunc(Time("1h")))    # Ok
print(myfunc(Length("1m")))  # Type error?
```

The second call to `myfunc()` is a type error, since I'm passing a `Length` instead of a `Time`. However `mypy` is happy with the code. So I have some questions:

1. Why doesn't mypy catches the error?
2. How to do it properly?

For 1. I guess that something fishy is happening in pint's `Quantity` implementation. I tried:

```py
foo = Quantity("3 pounds")
reveal_type(foo)
```

and the revealed type is `Any` instead of `Quantity` which is very suspicious.

So I tried removing the base class `Quantity` from my `Time` and `Length` classes (i.e: they derive now from `object` instead of `Quantity`), and in this case, `mypy` correctly manages the typing errors.

But it fails again as soon as I try something like `Length("60km")/Time("1h")`. `mypy` complains that `Length` object does not implement the required method for performing that division (although the code works ok at runtime because, after all, `Length` and `Time` `__new__()` method is returning a `Quantity` object which *does* implement the arithmetical operations).

So, again, is there any workaround for making the idea work both at run-time and for `mypy`?

Comment: Can't tell you why `Quantity` is recognized as `Any`; there is too much magic going on inside pint, I guess. However, as `mypy --strict` also reports, subclassing `Any` means the subclass itself is `Any`, so your annotation of the `myfunc()` parameter is effectively useless. You could even write `print(t.foo)` inside `myfunc()` and mypy wouldn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Pint has a wrapper function that can do that for you: `@ureg.check('[time]')` that goes right above your function's definition.

##### Discussion

In general, python does not enforce typing hints (see official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)). If you want to enforce such behavior, the best thing you can do is utilize the `isinstance()` native method (find details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)).
However, in your example, you are not even creating a new type. Both `Time` and `Length` classes will return a pint.util.Quantity object. Hence the following example would **always raise an error**, even for the `Time` defined objects:

```
def myfunc(t: Time) -> str:  # does not work!
if isinstance(t, Time):
    return f"The duration is {t}"
else:
    raise DimensionalityError(t, "[time]")
```

##### Solutions

1. A simple suggestion is to define a function that checks the quantity type:

   ```
   def qtype_check(obj: Quantity, q_type: str):
       qtype_str = f"[{q_type}]"
       if not obj.check(qtype_str):
           raise DimensionalityError(obj, qtype_str)
   ```

   And then simply call it in your method of choice:

   ```
   def myfunc(t: Quantity) -> str:
       qtype_check(t, 'time')
       return f"The duration is {t}"
   ```
2. A more elegant solution, if you need to keep your class definition, would be to additionally define your quantity classes as e.g. `MyQuantity`, with a class attribute `_qtype` that you change in each type definition. This way, you avoid writing the same error code snippet multiple times. Additionally, you can incorporate the qtype_check in the class, and invoke it through the type class of your choice (e.g.`Time.qtype_check(value)`), avoiding the hassle of having to remember how to define the class type string every time. Here are the definitions:

   ```
   from pint import Quantity, DimensionalityError


   class MyQuantity(Quantity):
       _qtype: str = "[]"

       def __new__(cls, v: str | Quantity) -> Quantity:
           obj = Quantity(v)
           cls.qtype_check(obj)
           return obj

       @classmethod
       def qtype_check(cls, obj: Quantity):
           if not obj.check(cls._qtype):
               raise DimensionalityError(obj, cls._qtype)


   class Time(MyQuantity):
       _qtype = "[time]"


   class Length(MyQuantity):
       _qtype = "[length]"


   def myfunc(t: Quantity) -> str:
       Time.qtype_check(t)
       return f"The duration is {t}"
   ```
3. Best of all is to simply use the pint-provided wrapper function, which can automatically check input units for you! [Here](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/wrapping.html#checking-dimensionality) is the documentation. In your case it would look like:

   ```
   @ureg.check('[time]')
   def myfunc(t: Quantity) -> str:
       return f"The duration is {t}"
   ```